# C# .NET Core Pass HTML form variable to controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having trouble passing a variable from a html form to a controller within my .NET core project. The variable I am passing to the controller is then used in an interface method call.

My data model for the form:

```
public class JourneyFormModel
{
    public string fromStationCode { get; set; }
}
```

my form:

```
@model SplitTrainTicket.Models.JourneyFormModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("JounreyDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="form-horizontal col-md-6">

    <div class="autocomplete">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fromStationCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "autocomplete", id = "departStationPicker", @placeholder = "Departing From" } })
    </div>
}
```

And my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]

 public IActionResult GetResults(JourneyFormModel form)
    {
        return Ok(_repository.GetAllResults(form.fromStationCode));
    }
```

It seems that the value is null when form.toStationCode is passed to my GetAllResultsMethod. I have tired this with manually with a string and it seems to work fine. Just seems to be an issue getting the string from the form field.

This is also my interface if it is any help:

```
public interface IJourneyDetailsRepository
{
    List<JourneyModel> GetAllResults(string fromStation);
}
```

Thanks in advance for anybody who reads this :)

Comment: Couple questions: 1) It seems like `fromStationCode` is a primary key and identity from a table, and you're putting it out there to let users change it? 2) Your form posts back to home controller jounreyDetails method but your controller example shows a different one. 3) Your controller example doesn't have [HttpPost] annotation so it's a GET method. Your form and the controller don't talk to each other.

Comment: My bad, I have made edits

Comment: Still no luck when changing the controller annotation to HttpPost

Comment: Please read my question #2. Your form is posting back /home/jounreyDetails but your controller (well I don't know the name of the controller) only has GetResults method. Your form is not talking to your controller.

Comment: I've changed the controller name from GetResults to JourneyDetails, which is the view I wish to use to display results. I get results back but it's in JSON format and bypasses the table I made originally to display the data

Comment: I guess you're confused about the GET and POST requests/methods. When you don't put [HttpPost], the method is a GET method. That will map to requests like /home/journeyDetails from the browser URL. If you want to use what it returns as the view to display results, that's completely fine. But if you put a parameter there, that parameter is called query parameter. It would come from (by default, unless you change your route mappings) the ? mark from the url. For example /home/journeyDetails?from=portland. The controller method will capture "portland" and put it in as that parameter.

Comment: When you want to create a form with inputs, and post the inputs back to server, you need to create ANOTHER method marked as [HttpPost]. Form generally uses POST method to post data back to the server. You can't reuse your GET method for the form post. So in your case, you can keep the JourneyDetails as the GET method, and create another POST method (maybe something like Update?) that takes `JourneyDetails` as the parameter. And update your form to post back to this POST method instead of the GET method.

Comment: I see. I will spend some time on this. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: My form definitely  posts to the server as I can see the fromStation variable when I returned in a content view from the JourneyDetails controller

Answer (score 1):

> Just seems to be an issue getting the string from the form field.

The action name in the Html.BeginForm is `JounreyDetails`, while you want to post the form to `GetResults` action, you need to change it.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetResults", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```